# Linux - How to diff all files which have same name but different extensions in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Say in the current directory there are some files called:

`test1.out, test2.out, test3.out ...`

`test1.expect, test.expect, test3.expect ...`

I would like to compare each test.out with its corresponding test.expect, like:

```
diff test1.out test1.expect
diff test2.out test2.expect
```

and so on. I would like to know how could I achieve this more efficiently. Thank you!

I am not very familiar with linux shell. I have tried things like:

`for i in *.out; do diff "$i" "$i.expect"; done`

but I realize that this is not correct because `$i` includes the `.out` extension.

Comment: @yacc I got /bin/bash

Comment: This might be a dupe, but not particularly of the chosen target.  The OP does not couch it that way, and interpreting or solving it in terms of looping over pairs -- though that could be done -- leads to comparatively worse results than not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Bash, you have a lot of powerful variations on parameter expansion.  For example, in this variation on your attempt:

```
for i in *.out; do diff "$i" "${i/%out/expect}"; done
```

The `"${i/%out/expect}"` expands to the value of shell variable `i`, with the trailing `out` (if any) replaced by `expect`.

[The bash man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) and [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) are both good references for bash features and capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
find dir1 -iname "*.out" -exec basename -s .out {} \; | xargs  -I % diff dir1/%.out dir2/%.expect
```